# What is the 1D and 2D Gamma matrices satisfying the Clifford Algebra?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The Clifford algebra
$\Gamma^m\Gamma^n + \Gamma^n\Gamma^m=2\delta^{mn}$

What is the 1D and 2D Gamma matrices here?

Comment: You might get more help if you improve the question: for example by explaining that you want representations of a Clifford algebra. Grammar also helps :-) 

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to be to identify the Clifford algebras $Cl(0,1)$ and $Cl(0,2)$ in the usual mathematics notation of, say, [*Spin Geometry*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3d9JkN8w3X8C) by Lawson and Michelsohn.  It is very easy to show that
$$Cl(0,1) \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$Cl(0,2) \cong \mathbb{R}(2),$$
where $\mathbb{R}(2)$ is the algebra of $2\times 2$ real matrices.

There are two inequivalent one-dimensional irreducible representations of $Cl(0,1)$, where the gamma matrix (here a real number) is $\Gamma^1=\pm 1$.

There is a unique two-dimensional irreducible representation of $Cl(0,2)$, where the two gamma matrices can be given by
$$\Gamma^1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\Gamma^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I thought the question was asking for the representations of (all?) clifford algebras in one and two dimensions.

Comment: Indeed, but the quickest path to the representation theory of Clifford algebras is via their classification, since they are isomorphic to either one or two copies of matrix algebras.

Comment: Why can't Gamma^2 be 0 i
-i 0
?

Comment: Obviously, that should be arranged in 2x2 matrix form

Comment: It can, of course, but that representation is the complexification of a real representation equivalent to the one I wrote down.